# How to call a column dynamically in the WHERE clause in SQL

Tags: sql, dynamic-sql, mysql-variables

I'm trying to figure out how to call the column in the table where the column name matches the value of a declared variable. In this example, Tbl_B has columns labeled as DPS_YYYYMM such as 'DPS_201911', 'DPS_201910', 'DPS_201909'.... I need to find a way to call the correct column from Tbl_B for the given YYYYMM that matches the @Var. Can you please help?

| Campaign_ID | DPS_201911 | DPS_201910 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 345 | 123 |

```
DECLARE @Var varchar(50)
SET @Var = '201911'

 SELECT ?????
 From Tbl_B
 WHERE campaign_Id = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Dynamic sql` like below

```
DECLARE @Var varchar(50), @sql varchar(max)
SET @Var = '201911'
set @Var='DPS_'+ @Var;
set @sql='SELECT '+@Var+'
From Tbl_B
WHERE campaign_Id = 1'
EXEC (@sql)
```